# Web Scraping Login without SSL CERT

Tags: python, ssl, vps

I have created a web scraper in python to scrape various suppliers stock quantities for products we distribute for them(with their permission). I have a VPS Server and wanted to know if scraping suppliers websites that require a login is a security risk without a verified SSL Cert. The Python code will live on the VPS Server.

Some suppliers have issues with their SSL Cert causing the program to fail unless i use`verify=False` in the python get request.

Comment: Can you login to that same suppliers in the browser without any issues or do you have a browser warning and you need to accept the exception for that certificate in order to be able to proceed to the login page?

Comment: Do NOT use `verify=False`. You void all interests of using TLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specific use case for the scraper. SSL/TLS is used to protect the data exchanged between the endpoints (i.e. your scraper and the web servers) against sniffing and tampering.

If no sensitive data are transmitted and you don't care about somebody sniffing or modifying the data then you can disable certificate validation. But be sure that you really don't care: you can no longer be sure that the data you've got from the server are really the data you've requested since a man in the middle might have modified your request sent to the server and/or modified the response from the server or just made up its own response without even contacting the server.